# How to validate @QuerydslPredicate in spring @RestController?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-data-rest, spring-restcontroller

I'm using `spring-data-rest` to expose a database content via a spring servlet. Using `@QuerydslPredicate` for being able to send a filter via HTTP GET, like:

`localhost:8080/persons?firstname=john&lastname=doe`

Question: is it possible to tell the `Predicate` validation rules? Eg that the specific fields may not be `null`, eg lastname?

```
@RestController
public class PersonServlet {
    @GetMapping("/persons")
    public Iterable<Person> getPersons(
            @QuerydslPredicate(root = Person.class) com.querydsl.core.types.Predicate predicate,
            Pageable pageable) {
        return dao.findAll(predicate, pageable);
    }

    @Entity     
    public class Person {
        private String firstname;
        private String lastname;
        private String age;
        //many more fields
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be no way validating eg `QPerson.lastname != null`.

So I used the following approach adding `@Valid Person` as get parameter and adding validation constraints like `@NotNull`.

```
@RestController
public class PersonServlet {
    @GetMapping("/persons")
    public Iterable<Person> getPersons(
            @QuerydslPredicate(root = Person.class) com.querydsl.core.types.Predicate predicate,
            Pageable pageable,
            @Valid Person p) {
        return dao.findAll(predicate, pageable);
    }

    @Entity     
    public class Person {
        private String firstname;

        @NotNull
        private String lastname;

        private String age;
        //many more fields
    }
}
```